# Why is the WorkflowType in Drupal 8.5 Content Moderation so large?

Tags: workflows

I would like to create a custom WorkflowType in Drupal 8.5.  I looked at the Content Moderation source, and it is a massive set of code.  I don't mind coding, but is all the source for Content Moderation specific to a WorkflowType or is it a lot of boilerplate?

What I really want to know is if that massive amount of code is required for a new WorkflowType, as in created from scratch?

As an example, if I had a doctor's office.  The patient needs surgery, but that surgery requires lots of approvals in the workflow.  Each state may have its own content type or a simply approval of an existing content type instance.

A simpler one is an employee wanting time off.

I don't know another way to ask other than this specific question.

I have looked here,

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/workflows/overview

"In order to create workflows you need to install a module that provides a workflow type."

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21workflows%21src%21Entity%21Workflow.php/class/Workflow/8.5.x

and,

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/workflows/tests/modules/workflow_type_test

I was able to get the test module to work.  It does not seem as large.